# How to access values in array column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with one column.  Each row of that column has an Array of String values:

Values in my Spark 2.2 Dataframe

```
["123", "abc", "2017", "ABC"]
["456", "def", "2001", "ABC"]
["789", "ghi", "2017", "DEF"]

org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col: array]

root
|-- col: array (nullable = true)
|    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

What is the best way to access elements in the array?  For example, I would like extract distinct values in the fourth element for the year 2017 (answer "ABC", "DEF").

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Since Spark 2.4.0, there is a new function `element_at($array_column, $index)`.

[See Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#element_at(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,value:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

Comment: This is very helpful. Saved a lot of time. I was planning to write a UDF to do this which was erroring out. This answer is great.

Comment: I wish this existed in Spark 2.3.0. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: @AlexMoore-Niemi: You can use `getItem`, see the other answers here.

Comment: note: index start at 1

Answer (score 19):

```
 df.where($"col".getItem(2) === lit("2017")).select($"col".getItem(3))
```

see `getItem` from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Comment: Interesting to note is that getItem will simply return NULL if the index is out of range rather than thrown an exception.

Comment: and contrary to element_at, index start at 0

Answer (score 10):

> What is the best way to access elements in the array?

Accessing elements in an array column is by [getItem](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@getItem(key:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) operator.

> **getItem(key: Any): Column** An expression that gets an item at position ordinal out of an array, or gets a value by key key in a `MapType`.

You could also use `(ordinal)` to access an element at `ordinal` position.

```
val ds = Seq(
  Array("123", "abc", "2017", "ABC"),
  Array("456", "def", "2001", "ABC"),
  Array("789", "ghi", "2017", "DEF")).toDF("col")
scala> ds.printSchema
root
 |-- col: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
scala> ds.select($"col"(2)).show
+------+
|col[2]|
+------+
|  2017|
|  2001|
|  2017|
+------+
```

It's just a matter of personal choice and taste which approach suits you better, i.e. `getItem` or simply `(ordinal)`.

And in your case `where` / `filter` followed by `select` with `distinct` give the proper answer (as @Will did).

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val ds = Seq(
 Array("123", "abc", "2017", "ABC"),
 Array("456", "def", "2001", "ABC"),
 Array("789", "ghi", "2017", "DEF")).toDF("col")

ds.withColumn("col1",element_at('col,1))
.withColumn("col2",element_at('col,2))
.withColumn("col3",element_at('col,3))
.withColumn("col4",element_at('col,4))
.drop('col)
.show()

+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
| 123| abc|2017| ABC|
| 456| def|2001| ABC|
| 789| ghi|2017| DEF|
+----+----+----+----+
```