# get first N elements from dataframe ArrayType column in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with rows as -

```
1   |   [a, b, c]
2   |   [d, e, f]
3   |   [g, h, i]
```

Now I want to keep only the first 2 elements from the array column.

```
1   |   [a, b]
2   |   [d, e]
3   |   [g, h]
```

How can that be achieved?

Note - Remember that I am not extracting a single array element here, but a part of the array which may contain multiple elements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract an element from a array in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254928/how-to-extract-an-element-from-a-array-in-pyspark)

Comment: I already saw that answer, but that is not what I want. I don't want a single item from array, rather I am looking for first N elements.

Comment: @pault interestingly enough, linked solution does not seem to work with Spark 2.3.1 (throws exception). Any ideas?

Comment: @pault mystery solved! A new user had decided to alter OP's code in linked answer, rendering it wrong (restored it)...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585279/how-to-access-values-in-array-column  not convinced we need to create a tempview for this

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's how to do it with the API functions.

Suppose your DataFrame were the following:

```python
df.show()
#+---+---------+
#| id|  letters|
#+---+---------+
#|  1|[a, b, c]|
#|  2|[d, e, f]|
#|  3|[g, h, i]|
#+---+---------+

df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- id: long (nullable = true)
# |-- letters: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

You can use square brackets to access elements in the `letters` column by index, and wrap that in a call to `pyspark.sql.functions.array()` to create a new `ArrayType` column.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn("first_two", f.array([f.col("letters")[0], f.col("letters")[1]])).show()
#+---+---------+---------+
#| id|  letters|first_two|
#+---+---------+---------+
#|  1|[a, b, c]|   [a, b]|
#|  2|[d, e, f]|   [d, e]|
#|  3|[g, h, i]|   [g, h]|
#+---+---------+---------+
```

Or if you had too many indices to list, you can use a list comprehension:

```python
df.withColumn("first_two", f.array([f.col("letters")[i] for i in range(2)])).show()
#+---+---------+---------+
#| id|  letters|first_two|
#+---+---------+---------+
#|  1|[a, b, c]|   [a, b]|
#|  2|[d, e, f]|   [d, e]|
#|  3|[g, h, i]|   [g, h]|
#+---+---------+---------+
```

---

For pyspark versions 2.4+ you can also use [`pyspark.sql.functions.slice()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.slice):

```python
df.withColumn("first_two",f.slice("letters",start=1,length=2)).show()
#+---+---------+---------+
#| id|  letters|first_two|
#+---+---------+---------+
#|  1|[a, b, c]|   [a, b]|
#|  2|[d, e, f]|   [d, e]|
#|  3|[g, h, i]|   [g, h]|
#+---+---------+---------+
```

`slice` may have better performance for large arrays (note that start index is 1, not 0)

Comment: Damn... As I said, I have gone rusty - could not even remember the *existence* of `pyspark.sql.functions.array`... :(

Comment: This doesn't work for me for a similar problem. I get the following error:
"Can't extract value from probability#6225: need struct type but got struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>;"

Comment: @LePuppyle my guess is that you have a VectorUDT not an array. For thst, you will need a `udf` - try [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39555864/how-to-access-element-of-a-vectorudt-column-in-a-spark-dataframe).

Comment: `AnalysisException: "Field name should be String Literal, but it's 0;"`

Answer (score 4):

Either my pyspark skills have gone rusty (I confess I don't hone them much anymore nowadays), or this is a tough nut indeed... The only way I managed to do it is by using SQL statements:

```python
spark.version
#  u'2.3.1'

# dummy data:

from pyspark.sql import Row
x = [Row(col1="xx", col2="yy", col3="zz", col4=[123,234, 456])]
rdd = sc.parallelize(x)
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd)
df.show()
# result:
+----+----+----+---------------+
|col1|col2|col3|           col4|
+----+----+----+---------------+
|  xx|  yy|  zz|[123, 234, 456]|
+----+----+----+---------------+

df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
df2 = spark.sql("SELECT col1, col2, col3, (col4[0], col4[1]) as col5 FROM df")
df2.show()
# result:
+----+----+----+----------+ 
|col1|col2|col3|      col5|
+----+----+----+----------+ 
|  xx|  yy|  zz|[123, 234]|
+----+----+----+----------+
```

For future questions, it would be good to follow the suggested guidelines on [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples).